# Access WEBrick from a different PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I used:

```
rails s 

run webrick on 0.0.0.0:3000
```

But I could't reach the web application from another PC.

How can I achieve this in Rails 3?

Comment: Please clarify, How did you try to access the web App from other system's browser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default binding IP is 0.0.0.0, so the problem can be your firewall blocking that port. Try to use `rails s -b IP_ADDRESS -p PORT` to be sure the problem is with your firewall.

Btw. Linux, Osx, Windows?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 isn't a port, it's an IP address.

Comment: you are right... the 0.0.0.0 is important because it's binding to all network interfaces not just to localhost. I thought to 3000 when I had written "blocking that port"

Comment: +1 to both your answers and thank you for correcting me. I spoke incorrectly and that's a big no-no. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Nucc got it right. You should be able to access the website via your IP address but from what I understand you are trying to reach it via 0.0.0.0 (I was mistaken thinking this is a null address, my bad) as Nucc correctly states 0.0.0.0 maps to INADDR_ANY so will map to all of your network interfaces.

If you want to specify a specific IP address use (assuming your IP address is 192.168.0.50):

```
rails s -b 192.168.0.50
```

I would keep the default port at 3000 just so you don't conflict with a real web server if you're running one on your computer but if you aren't feel free to change it to 80 like so:

```
rails s -b 192.168.0.50 -p 80
```

The -b command line parameter changes the IP address WEBrick binds to and the -p parameter changes the default port. For a full list of options type:

```
rails s -h
```

As has also been stated you need to make sure the port is open if you're using a software firewall. If you weren't trying to use 0.0.0.0 but were using the correct IP address from the second computer then this is probably the culprit.

Now to get to your rails site from another computer you would simply type in a browswer:

```
http://192.168.0.50:3000
```

Or if you've changed the default port to the standard port of 80 you could just use:

```
http://192.168.0.50
```

Answer (score 5):

(sorry, I can't reply :()

> "The default binding IP address is 0.0.0.0 which can't be reached from another computer since that's a non-routable address."

Sorry, but it's not true. Here the `0.0.0.0` means INADDR_ANY, so it binds to all interfaces...

Answer (score 2):

If connections are through the **LAN**, then use the command **ifconfig** on your terminal find the **inet** address, it will something like **192.148.0.100,** and use it **192.148.0.100:3000**, **3000** is the port where the server is running.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with subdomains? e.g. how to access account.localhost:3000/ @Nithin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a firewall blocking that port. Also make sure that you include the port when you're trying to hit it from the other machine. It should Just Work as far as rails goes.